# How can counting the number of cracks in glass tell you about the speed of impact?

Tags: collision, material-science

A recent article, [Counting cracks in glass gives speed of projectile](http://www.sciencenews.org/view/generic/id/350088/description/Counting_cracks_in_glass_gives_speed_of_projectile) (Andrew Grant, *Science News*, May 1 2013) indicates that the number of cracks in a broken glass can tell you information about the speed of the impact that broke it.

[image]

However, I'm not quite clear on how this is done and what the physics behind this mechanism is. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4995

Answer (score 5):

The explanation can be found in the author manuscript of the article  at [this HAL preprint](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/85/72/39/PDF/window.pdf) of the original journal article ([*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **110** no. 17 (2013), 174302](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.174302)). It is my understanding that, for larger times, the number of cracks is determined by minimizing the sum of stretching energy and fracture energy.

You can also read the [Physics Focus](http://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/48) piece that accompanies the journal article.